# How can an (unauthenticated) user's "Suggested Change" be managed with Django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a Django application for humanitarian aid coordination with about 600 projects, 1000 organizations.

- Users will range from IT professionals working in international development to people in rural areas with a smartphone and for whom English is a second or third language.
- We need a way to let users tell us where our data is wrong and suggest corrections - it's a
  legacy database with horrendous spelling and lots of stale contact
  details.
- I don't want to require user authentication, this would be a
  nightmare to administer.
- I don't want to have a wiki-type interface
  interacting directly with my database either, as it would be too easy for
  errors, deliberate or accidental.

I'd like to see a "Suggest changes" page for each model where users can submit recommendations, then have that data approved by an admin user with a single click. At the moment I'm working on a solution involving the django REST framework, saving the serialized data and the URL for an admin user to verify and submit instead of actually changing the instance.

Can anyone recommend a way to implement this, or a better solution?

EDIT: This is the structure of the main table I want to change. One of the complications is the number of relationships involved.

```
class Project(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=256)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_("Project Description"))#, config_name='awesome_ckeditor')
    startdate = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Start date")
    enddate = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="End date")
    notes = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.ForeignKey('ProjectStatus', null=True, verbose_name="Status")
    projecttype = models.ForeignKey('ProjectType', null=True, blank=True)

    person = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='ProjectPerson', null=True, blank=True)
    sector = models.ManyToManyField(
        'nhdb.PropertyTag', null=True, blank=True, related_name="project_sector",
        limit_choices_to={'path__startswith': "INV."})
    activity = models.ManyToManyField(
        'nhdb.PropertyTag', null=True, blank=True, related_name="project_activity",
        limit_choices_to={'path__startswith': "ACT."})
    beneficiary = models.ManyToManyField(
        'nhdb.PropertyTag', null=True, blank=True, related_name="project_beneficiary",
        limit_choices_to={'path__startswith': "BEN."})

    place = models.ManyToManyField("geo.AdminArea", through='ProjectPlace', null=True, blank=True)
    organization = models.ManyToManyField(Organization, through='ProjectOrganization', null=True, blank=True)
    stafffulltime = models.IntegerField(null=True, verbose_name=_('Full time staff'))
    staffparttime = models.IntegerField(null=True, verbose_name=_('Part time staff'))
```

Comment: Is your data structured or unstructured?

Comment: Structured. I've added the code for the main table which people should be able to suggest edits for.

Answer (score 0):

you could have this info go to a separate database table called suggestions with a foreign key relationship to the object being suggested to be updated.

If you did not want to risk having unauthorized people add anything to your database, you could even just have an email sent to an email chain which notifies the admins.

If that doesn't work, you could have text files saved in an edit directory somewhere on your server which wait to be worked by your admins.  There could be a separate RabbitMQ setup to automatically manage this workload etc...

Basically you have a ton of options.